# Running Satellite cable from wall plate, under carpet to opposite side

Tags: walls, carpet, low-voltage, cables

I want to route my satellite cables, which are currently poking out of a media plate on one side of the room, to their destination on the other side. The challenges that I face are:

1. Routing the cables from their current exit point back into the wall and out closer to, or preferably under, the carpet.
2. Threading the cables under the carpet to their destination.
3. Pulling the cable either out of the carpet, or back into the wall to a box that I can terminate them at.

From searching around, I feel that I should be able to manage 2 with minimal swearing and damage, using the fish tape to navigate it around.

I'm less sure about the termination on either end, without wires dangling about. The walls on all sides are supporting walls, with plasterboard in front of breeze-block.

Am I approaching this the wrong way, and should be looking at trunking?

Comment: Is this on a slab?

Comment: I’m not sure of the context here. It’s a ground floor, and under the carpet and insulation is concrete.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was asking about. What about running it around the perimeter of the room above carpet?

Comment: satrellite cables are fragile, if they encouter heavy furniture or much foot traffic they will fail,

Answer (score 3):

Running the cables around the baseboards using **surface-mount conduit** is a better idea.

Common trade names for conduit (or “raceway”) include “Panduit” and “Wiremold”.

Coax under carpet will create a lump and the coax will eventually be damaged.